# How to enable the vertical lines in atom?

Tags: editor, atom-editor

The screenshot on the [Atom.io](https://atom.io) site shows, that the editor has vertical lines which show how much a line is "tabbed" in. I wonder if this is an additional package or if it can be enabled in atom by default.
[image: sample image]

Comment: what color theme is that? looks nice

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Open up your settings panel, usually by selecting the `Preferences` option in the `Edit` menu. Inside there, select the `Editor` submenu. In the `Invisibles` section, select the option titled `Show Indent Guide`. The vertical line indentation markers will then appear for you like in the image.

Comment: On the Mac, it's not the `Edit` menu, but the `Atom` menu where you find the preferences.

Comment: Atom 1.60.0 on MacOS: Shift + Cmd + P for the command palette -> Editor: Toggle Indent Guide

Answer (score 10):

On atom version 1.40.1 (Windows), Goto `File` -> `Settings` -> `<>Editor` -> `[]Show Indent Guide`

Answer (score 4):

It's a little different in Windows version v1.40.1

Settings > Editor > Show Indent Guide

Answer (score 3):

First, type `ctrl-shift-p`, open the Command Palette.
Then enter 'indent guide'. Select `Editor:Toggle Indent Guide`.

Answer (score 2):

If you additionally want to customize the soft wrap vertical line…

*[Settings and Preferences](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#settings-and-preferences)* → *Editor* → *Preferred Line Length* (or [via customization file](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#configuration-key-reference)).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

[image]

**Result**

Please note the guideline now displayed.

[image]